# CSS How do I radius the border of a card?

Tags: css

I want to radius the border of the card but the code does not work properly..
Here is the code I used.

```
   .card{ 
     box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #333333;
     transition: 0.3s;
     border-radius: 30px;
     width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not work properly"?

Comment: But it does not seem to be a problem. See this: https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-nobel-yrlnfs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add border `border:2px solid black;`

```
.card{ 
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #333333; 
    transition: 0.3s; 
    border:2px solid black;
    border-radius: 30px; 
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make more space between text and border you can add `padding` to this code:

```
card{ 
     box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 #333333;
     transition: 0.3s;
     border-radius: 30px;
     width: 100%;
     border: 1px solid #000;
 }
```